# Apache on Windows and Fiddler

Tags: apache, fiddler

I need to monitor HTTP traffic in my dev env which is PHP/Apache/Windows. But Apache seems to refuse the HTTP requests coming from fiddler which sits between the browser and Apache.
Error is `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

I suppose there should be some configuration on Apache which allows traffic via Fiddler. Can any one help me with it?

Comment: What does the error log show? Are you sure it works without Fiddler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What windows version are you using?

What browser are you using?

Does the Apache reside on localhost?

Try disabling IP6 support (in the `Fiddler options -> General -> uncheck "Enable IPv6 if available"`)

If apache is on localhost try `http://machinename:port` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:port` or `http://localhost:port`

Also check [Fiddler know issues](http://fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/help/knownissues.asp)

Comment: This is, indeed, most likely the correct answer.  Try using http://ipv4.fiddler as the address, and this will ensure that the IPv4 interface is used.

Alternatively, configure your Apache server to listen on the IPv6 adapter as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! IPv6 disabling did the trick. Can u please tell me the background info on why?

Thanks Again!

Comment: I'm not totally sure either, but it has something to do with windows vista mapping localhost per default to IPv6 and e.g. apache not listening on the IPv6 adapter. Or your windows/browser not using a proxy for localhost domains. You could also try adding a '.' like this http://localhost./

Comment: Yes, by default http://machinename will point to the IPv6 port, on which Apache does not listen by default.  So you can either configure Apache to listen on IPv6, or explicitly ask for the IPv4 port (using http:/ipv4.fiddler).  Using http://127.0.0.1 would work but for the fact that WinINET will not proxy traffic for this address by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your browser and Fiddler are installed on the same machine and the deve enviroment is remote.  I would install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and capture the native browser requests, and the ones proxied through Fiddler.  See what is different between them.  I would seem they would be comming form the same src IP, so I would look at the various HTTP request headers, and see what is different.